# Sublime layout split into 3 panel, to create custom layout

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any way I can split layout into 3 ? I got this snippet from net

```
self.window.set_layout({
    "cols": [0, 0.5, 1],
    "rows": [0, 0.5, 1],
    "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
})
```

But this will split in to two. I want to 3 like this
[image]

Any ideas ? I tried changing the values but no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keymap Setting (*Preferences -> Key Binding User -> Add inside brackets*)

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+7"],
    "caption": "2 cols (full - 3)",
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
        { "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
          "rows": [0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0],
          "cells": [ [0, 0, 1, 3], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3] ]
        }
}
```

**Sublime View:**

[image]

This structure helps you to make yourself any design in Sublime Text.

```
         0.0                             0.5                           1.0
          +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+

         0,0                             1,0                           2,0
   0.0    +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |   0,1                              1,1                           2,1
  0.33    |                               +-----------------------------+
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |   0,2                              1,2                           2,2
  0.66    |                               +-----------------------------+
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |   0,3                             1,3                           2,3
   1.0    +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: @Achayan can you look this structure desing help you make any desgn on your self.